# When I write {member.mention} the bot writes <@1234567890>

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

This is my code

```
from nextcord.ext import commands
import nextcord
from nextcord import Member, Embed
import token_ld

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=nextcord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member: Member):
    channel= bot.get_channel(1069001573583294587)
    embed = Embed(title=f"Добро пожаловать {member.mention}!", colour= 0x8B0000)
    embed.set_footer(text="by Laker")
    embed.set_image(url='https://i.imgur.com/PVqYbWN.png')
    role = nextcord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=1081959567652565044)
    await member.add_roles(role)

bot.run(token_ld.TOKEN)
```

and in line embed = Embed(title=f"Добро пожаловать {member.mention}!", colour= 0x8B0000), bot writes member.mention like a <@1234567890>, idk why

i looked my old codes and exactly the same, but it works there

Comment: Why should it write something different? And what?

Answer (score 0):

The mention system on discord works as the following: `<@USERID>`

If the User isn't loaded on your discord client you just see the `<@USERID>` thing and not the real mention with `@username`.

Maybe restart your discord and it should work again.

It's definite not an error of the bot.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to mention users or roles with your bot, you must first pass the [`allowed_mentions`](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#allowedmentions) parameter to the initialisation of the `Bot` object.

```py
bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix="!", 
    intents=nextcord.Intents.all(), 
    allowed_mentions=nextcord.AllowedMentions(roles=True, users=True, everyone=False)
    # edit as required
)
```